# How to get a list of subdirectories that have a long path (>256) of parent directory?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

There are directories with a path that exceeds 256 characters(unc path). I need to get a list of subdirectories.
The .Net class methods:

```
DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories, Directory.GetDirectories
```

and the WinApi methods:

```
 FindFirst (W / A), FindNext (W / A)
```

do not work with long paths with the following error:

> DirectoryNotFoundException.

The substitution of short paths (obtained using `GetShortPathName`) also does not give results. However, Windows Explorer walks along such paths perfectly. 
Tell me, please, how to get a list of subdirectories that have a long path of parent directory?

.Net 4.7.1, OS: Windows 10

Comment: would [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/) help ?

Comment: You need .NET 4.6.2, what is your version? Then .NET doesn't throw a `PathTooLongException` anymore but just passes what the OS throws(in case of an error).

Comment: I use a library called AlphaFS. It can deal with these things and has corresponding methods to basically all the file/directory/path methods that support long file names as well as other things like transactions. Note that I'm not affiliated, just a happy user. http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com

Comment: Thanks you.
I changed the parameter "Enable Win32 long path" and also changed the config and manifest, but it did not help.
Third-party libraries are fine, but Windows Explorer is unlikely to use third-party libraries. It must be something in WinApi

Comment: Thanks pinkfloydx33. By the way, the library "alfafs" works and I will use it if other solution not find.